# How do I remove the menu bar icon associated with an app without deleting the app? (macOS Catalina)

Tags: macos, terminal

I use a great app called magnet that allows me to use keyboard shortcuts to resize windows to certain portions of of the screen. I would like to remove its icon from the menu bar because my menu bar is already very cluttered. But I still need this app to be running at all times. (Yes, I've checked the app's settings; there's no option to remove the menu bar icon.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bartender](https://www.macbartender.com/) will let you organize and hide icons on your menu bar. This is probably the best-known solution.

Another alternative that you might want to check out is [Vanilla](https://matthewpalmer.net/vanilla/).

I use Bartender and highly recommend it, but it’s worth downloading both and checking them both out.

*Before you ask, no, there is no way to do this without 3rd party software, unless that feature is added by the developer.*